# Twitter typeahead with azure search for MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, twitter-typeahead, azure-cognitive-search

I wanted to make use of the Twitter typeahead with my ASP.Net mvc application. I am using Azure search for my search text box. Now i wanted use Twitter typeahead to provide the user drop down with suggestions and hint the typing textbox. 
How can I use this with the azure search?

Thanks 
Pavan

Answer (score 1):

Liam from our team put together an example for using Twitter typehead + Azure Search some time ago. You can find it here:
http://azsearchsuggestions.codeplex.com/